# Using SQL Can I get incremental changes in data from query results? Loops?

Tags: sql, loops, while-loop, report, incremental-build

NOTE: I am not making changes to a database. I am creating a report.

The purpose of the report is to show pending orders that need to be assembled for shipment, but not until there is enough stock to fill the order. An order includes multiple inventory items, but the inventory on hand must be >= the ordered amount per each inventory item and in order by oldest date first before the order can be added to the report.

I've written this to where it pulls the orders, but I need it to loop through to the next order and carry over the quantity of inventory On Hand from the calculation prior to this order. When the calculation is < 0, I don't need to see the order.

EXAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
Order Date | Order No | Item No | Quantity Ordered | On Hand | Available Qty

2015-01-01     123456     555555    50                 60        10
2015-01-02     555544     555555    10                 10        00
```

Notice On Hand says 60 for Item No 555555 in the first row. This is the actual QOH, but the report needs to subtract the amount that was ordered in the previous line from my On Hand stock, and give me the remainder, or show the new available total under On Hand. When my On Hand amount can't fulfill an order, I don't want the order to appear on my report. My current report shows On Hand to be 60 in both rows, and instead of zero, like above, it just subtracts 10 from 60, as if it's my only order.

I don't know what approach to take to do this type of incremental change in a field, but I am assuming it involves a loop and a variable (If I need to add a variable, then it needs to begin with the actual Quantity on hand), ???? Could someone please assist me with a direction? My search to answer this has only left me more unsure of how to do this. I can provide the SQL, but it is rather complicated, so I am trying to keep this on a more general level.

Answer (score 0):

"Looping" should be used as a last resort in SQL.  You can do so using a [CURSOR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) but they tend to run slower and require more work than standard SQL commands.

I would recommend trying to break this problem down into smaller tables using sub-queries / CTEs (Common Table Expressions).  Can you create a query that shows the total on hand amounts for each item number?  Now put that into a sub-query and start building on top of it.

Comment: I can definitely give it a try, but wouldn't that mean that I have a report that is however many layers deep as I set it up to be (not dynamic) and would determine the number of report results on my report? And wouldn't each layer require the previous layers before it to be used to find the quantity on hand amount? Also, we have many thousands of item numbers.

Comment: After re-reading your post I think what you are looking for is the lead and lag commands introduced in SQL Server 2012.  They let you get results in rows above or below the current row.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: This definitely sounds like a possibility. I have been looking at the Over clause, but now I'm working with Lag/Over. I just have to figure out how to get it to do what I need. Thanks.